# Generate a matrix with a specific number repetitions for specific numbers

Tags: r, matrix, sample

I would like to generate a matrix that contains 0,1 and 2, and have this values in different porportions, let´s say 90% 1, 5% 0 and 5% 2.

I can generate a matrix with this numbers using this:

```
test <- matrix(0, 10, 10)
test[] <- apply(test, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0,1,2),1))
```

But I don´t know how to generate a matrix sampling 1 90% of the times and 0 and 2 5% of the times.

Do you know how I could achive this?

Comment: `sample()` has an optional parameter called `prob`. Evaluate `?sample` for details. That will be if you want the number of `0` to be *on average* 90%, etc. If you want an exact number of `0`, etc., construct a vector with the requisite number of `0`, `1`, `2` and then use `sample` to shuffle it.

Comment: Try `matrix(sample(0:2, size = 100, prob = c(.05, .9, .05), replace = TRUE), nrow = 10)`

Answer (score 3):

This should give what you want:

```
v <- rep(c(0, 1, 2), round(10 * 10 * c(0.05, 0.9, 0.05)))
matrix(sample(v), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#  [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#  [2,]    1    1    2    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#  [3,]    2    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    2     1
#  [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#  [5,]    1    0    1    1    1    2    1    1    1     1
#  [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#  [7,]    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
#  [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    1     1
#  [9,]    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     2
# [10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```